# C - Creating animation in terminal - auto-updating 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, animation

I'm trying to make an animation which will make a basic circle from dots. I got stuck, because i do not know how to make an array to auto-update herself to make an animation. My program has an issue, because it shows only the last point on circle and other, previous points has vanished due to system("clear") command, but i do not know how to make it the proper way.
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){

char tab[43][132];
int a, b, t;
double x_kropki, y_kropki;

for (t=0 ; t<360 ; t++) {
    x_kropki=floor(10*cos((t*pi)/180))+60;
    y_kropki=floor(10*sin((t*pi)/180))+20;
    for (a=0 ; a<43 ; a++, printf("\n")) for (b=0 ; b<132 ; b++) {
    if ((int)y_kropki==a && (int)x_kropki==b){
        tab[a][b]='.';
        printf("%c", tab[a][b]);
        }else {
            tab[a][b]=' ';
            printf("%c", tab[a][b]);
        }
    }
    system("clear");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all `system("clear")` is terrible practice. Second, using the terminal for an "*animation*" is not going to work very good, and if you can do it anyway it appears that you are required to know a lot more than you do.

Comment: I know that it is a terrible practice but I have to do this for university project. Is there any simply way to make an "animation" with parametric equation (like an circle equation above in my code)?

Comment: Write the data into the buffer and discharge the whole buffer. Instead of testing some weird stuff, use a single loop (rotation) and just write the next dot into the correct place in the buffer, then print the whole buffer. Horrible. But better yet is to explore console `gotoxy` functions, which are available in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

What is the animation supposed to look like? Do you want the circle to grow slowly? Then you need to add a *delay* (`sleep` or similar) or else it will finish the whole process too quickly for the screen to draw and for your eyes to notice.

Also you should not clear the progress after every new dot (of the 360 dots in total, it seems). To achieve that, you will need to change your approach a bit. Here's what the loop could look like:

1. Draw nothing
2. Draw dot 1
3. Clear
4. Draw dot 1 and 2
5. Clear
6. Draw dot 1 and 2 and 3

You see that after clearing, you need to repeat printing the progress so far. At loop iteration 180, you need to print the last 179 dots again *plus* the 180th. Wait a few milliseconds, then clear, then the same for 181.

How you do that? You repeat the `for` loop:

```
int dot, maxDots;
for (maxDots = 0; maxDots < 360; maxDots++) {
    for (dot = 0; dot < maxDots; dot++) {
        // your location calculations and printing for each dot
    }
    system("clear");
 }
```

This should at least give you some kind of growing circle. But you will notice that the printing approach is hard to get right, because once a line has been finished, you cannot go back.  If you start at the top and go your way around 180 degrees, down line by line, you will then need to go up line by line until you reach the top again. That won't work easily. Instead of printing directly, as @Weather Vane suggested, store the to-be-printed result of each animation stage in a buffer. That is an abstraction of on-screen coordinates. A very simple approach would be a two-dimensional array that you can manipulate freely, then print the whole array en bloc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The circle animation is just a simpler version of animation i have to do this for a university project. I'm just trying to make this simple animation work and then go on with the main project (it will be a point that is slowly drawing a spiral in a terminal and some other parametric equation). How do i store the result of each animation in a buffer?

Comment: Depends on what you are more comfortable with. One option: think of characters on screen as pixels. Then create a 2-dimensional bool array of the appropriate width and height where you flick the entry from `false` to `true` if a pixel should be drawn: `pixels[x][y] = true`. If you do not want this abstraction from characters to booleans, you can represent your circle as an list of lines (themselves `char` arrays) with space characters and set  `text[x][y] = '.'`. Then print the whole result.